# How can I determine the bandwidth of my network adapter?

Tags: windows-7, networking

What command can I use in windows 7 that will tell me how much bandwidth one of my LAN adapters has?

It needs to be able to send its output to a text file.

Comment: Are you looking for the negotiated port speed, such as 100Mb/s? or the current usage? or the remaining estimate based off of current usage?

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager have them both: current network usage and the port speed for all adapters. You can send screenshot of the task manager window.